# NeoVim: set signcolumn=number does not work. How to merge sign column with line number column?

Tags: vim, configuration, syntax-highlighting, neovim

When I add `set signcolumn=number` in to `init.vim` I get this message on startup:

> Error detected while processing ~/.config/nvim/init.vim:
> line   17:
> E474: Invalid argument: signcolumn=number
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

How to merge signs column with line number column in **NeoVim** ?

My **NeoVim** version:

```
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: "number", not "numbers".

Comment: @Matt Thank you for suggestion, but it does not change anything. Error still remains

Comment: You're using an outdated version then. Before asking a question you should 1) check your version number; 2) check `:help` to see if options are supported; 3) update to the last version etc. In particular, 0.4.4 doesn't support "signcolumn=number". You must update to 0.5.0.

Comment: @Matt Pacman is telling me that 0.4.4 is newest version even after `sudo pacman -Syy`.

Comment: And how is pacman relevant here?

Comment: @Matt it is main package manager of my OS,  it derminates which versions I can install or not.

Comment: Then you don't need `set signcolumn=number`, as your pacman knows better. You should trust him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to this problem is to upgrade NeoVim to version `0.5.0`. At the moment this version is not officially released. You can still install dev version.

---

### Installation guide

#### Windows

1. Extract [nvim-win64.zip](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim-win64.zip) (or [nvim-win32.zip](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim-win32.zip))
2. `Run nvim-qt.exe`

#### MacOS

1. Download [nvim-macos.tar.gz](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim-macos.tar.gz)
2. Extract: tar xzvf nvim-macos.tar.gz
3. `Run ./nvim-osx64/bin/nvim`

#### Linux (x64)

1. Download [nvim.appimage](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/nightly/nvim-linux64.tar.gz)
2. Run `chmod u+x nvim.appimage && ./nvim.appimage`
3. If your system does not have FUSE you can extract the appimage:

```
./nvim.appimage --appimage-extract
./squashfs-root/usr/bin/nvim
```

---

Official stable release is planed on Christmas 2020. [Here is project milestone](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/milestone/19)

Comment: Compiling from sources the `nightly` tag does not contain this patch yet. You really need the `master`.